# Why the instanceof Array return false for the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why `instanceof Array` returns false for the array.

See the given image more information.

[image]

Comment: Can you show how the `pricelists` is created?

Comment: Maybe it's coming from a different frame? This is why you should use `Array.isArray` not `instanceof Array`.

Answer (score 0):

The data must be parsed from json string before checking if it's an array.

You can use `Array.isArray` instead to check whether a given value is an array.

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3];
const obj = {};

console.log('is Array?', Array.isArray(numbers))
console.log('is Array?', Array.isArray(obj))

// however, this should also work
console.log(numbers instanceof Array)
```

Comment: What does the stringified data look like?

Answer (score 0):

`res.extra_info.pricelists` appears to be a JSON string. After you parse it you get an object with an Array `pricelists`. To validate this, check `Array.isArray(res.extra_info.pricelists)`.

**Update:**
`typeof(res.extra_info.pricelists)` won't work because it evaluates it as an `object`- see comment below. Use `Array.isArray` instead.

Logging a JSON string in console appears to expand it:

[image]

Comment: If it were a JSON string, it wouldn't be expandable like an array of objects in the console.

Comment: This is wrong because `typeof [] === "object"`, `typeof {} === "object"`, and `typeof null  === "object"`.

Comment: Yes it would be expandable. Will edit the answer to include a sample. @AluanHaddad good point, I'll update the answer to `Array.isArray`. This answer is really just the same as Alan's but I'll leave it up.